# Seam Classes and @Asynchronous processing related issue

Tags: asynchronous, seam

I have an Interface defined as:

```
public interface DocExporter{
      public void exportDoc();
}
```

with two implementing classes defined as:

```
@Service(value="docExporter")   
@Scope(value="BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class PdfDocExporter implements DocExporter{
   public void exportDoc(){
    // do Pdf Export stuff
   }
}
```

AND

```
@Service(value="docExporter")
@Scope(value="BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class ExcelDocExporter implements DocExporter{
   public void exportDoc(){
    // do Excel Export stuff
   }
 }
```

So can I say like :

```
@Name("docExportReporter")
@Scope(ScopeType.EVENT)
public class DocExportReporter {
@In("#{docExporter}")
private DocExporter pdfDocExporter;

@In("#{docExporter}")
private DocExporter excelDocExporter;

   @Asynchronous
   public void reportGen(){
             **excelDocExporter.exportDoc()**  // THIS THROWS Seam Exception @In attribute requires a not null value

   }
  }
```

I am new to Seam with Spring and would like to know if in both impl classes @Service would have values as "docExporter" (name of interface) or would it be like "pdfDocExporter" "excelDocExporter" ?

And with the above, I get @In attribute requires a non null value exception when using pdfDocExporter or excelDocExporter objects within the reportGen async method. Can two implementations of an interface be declared in a third class and work fine 
with Seam @Asynchronous annotation ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two components with the same name, otherwise Seam would not know which one to inject. Use two different names.

Comment: but 
1) if you look at the code, should they not be having the same @Service annotation i.e. `@Service(value="docExporter")` AND
2) What is implied by @In("#{SOMETHING}") , What is the Context when this "SOMETHING" injected (Session, Conversation, or Business Process Ctx)?

Comment: Yes Emir, I have that setting in the faces-config.xml file , The above is a sample example following an `@Service` already working in our prod app. However when I try to introduce a second impl. class of the interface, I get error with `@Asynchronous` annotated method that `@In` requires non null attribute.